# Soundcloud API: getting this simple example to work

Tags: javascript, html, api, soundcloud

I am using this Soundcloud example: http://connect.soundcloud.com/examples/basic.html

I'll copy the following code into an html doc:

```
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
  });

  $("#loadTracks").live("click", function(){
    SC.get("/tracks", {limit: 1}, function(tracks){
      var track = tracks[0];
      SC.oEmbed(track.uri, document.getElementById("track"));
    });
  });
</script>

<input type="button" id="loadTracks" class="button big" value="Get hottest track" />
<div id="track"></div>
```

Then I just replace the `YOUR_CLIENT_ID` with my client ID. When I try to rehost it, all I get  is this: [http://tobyfray[dot]com/](http://tobyfray.com/)

Should I also be using the following .js file too?:`http://connect.soundcloud[dot]com/examples/examples.js`

Anyway, any help on how to make it work exactly as the example over here would be greatly appreciated: http://connect.soundcloud.com/examples/basic.html

My example just has nothing happen when you click my button

Answer (score 0):

You're missing jQuery on your page.  If you look in your JavaScript console, you will see that `$` is not defined.

I wouldn't suggest following this example as-is anyway.  `jQuery.live()` was deprecated years ago.  `$('#loadTracks').on('click', function () {` will work much better, but you still need jQuery on your page to use this code example.  Otherwise, you can bind your click handler with `addEventListener`.